# facebook application misconfigured for login and unkonown host exception

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am totally stuck up in solving the following problem :

(the question is going to be big enough)

I am developing an android application. I want to create a facebook login for the same.
While I was working on my machine (Linux) I was able to perform the operations.
I have registered my application on Fb developer site. I could also login with Fb into my app. 
I had given permissions to gain email information also. Everything worked fine. And I was happy.
I am using deprecated methods.

Now when I moved the exact same code on my friends machine (windows), it is not working properly.(I mean not working  all, when I click on login button from my app, it unfortunately stops.)
I have followed all the steps correctly (as per my knowledge) on his machine also, like,
I have installed facebook sdk, installed the apk in his emulator (as per instructed on fb developer site). I have also checked logging to fb using the fb app from his emulator. Everything works fine.

But when I try to login from my application (the exact same code which works on my PC) 
I got following messages:

```
Sorry , Login failed t reach facebook servers. Please check your network connection 
or try again later (unable to resolve host "api.facebook.com"
No address associated with hostname [java.net.UnknownHostException]
```

but I know that the networked connection is working well.
and another message that I got is :
the flow successfully went to my apps page (after logging in ) and said that my app is

```
 misconfigured for facebook login
```

but I have not changed any settings of my app.
why is this happening?? I am really bugged up!

please help.
everything worked well on my pc but why not here?

another error:
error in logging in!!
and my onFaceBook error is also invoked
All these errors occur randomly